# Redirect output of less utility to a file

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, less

Here is what I did

```
less -N file1 > file2
```

what I want is writting file1 into file2 with line-numbers option.

But I failed with that.

Any suggestion to do that?
Why I failed to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use `less` for this job? The right tool is `nl`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the first question. What about the second? This nl-utility is really HELPFUL.

Comment: The answer to second question is "because `less` is file *viewer*, not editing tool and one cannot easily store its screen output to the file". In fact the main problem is that `less` output depends on where standard output is redirected - if it is not terminal, then all "operations" in the buffer are thrown away. For example compare `less -X -N -E file` with `less -X -N -E file | cat`.

Comment: @jimmij I did and I found two different outputs! Thanks that answers my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`less` is the wrong tool for the job.

You can use `cat` for that:

```
cat -n file1 >file2
```

Or `nl`:

```
nl -ba file1 >file2
```

Or `pr`:

```
pr -n -t -T file1 >file2
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed '/./=' file1 | sed '/./N; s/\n/\t/' >file2
```

Or `grep`:

```
grep -n . file1 | sed 's/:/\t/' >file2
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '{ $0 = NR "\t" $0 } 1' file1 >file2
```

Or again `awk`:

```
awk '{ sub(/^/, NR "\t") } 1' file1 >file2
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -pe '$_=$.."\t".$_' file1 >file2
```

Or again `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^/$.\t/' file1 >file2
```

Or `seq` and `paste`:

```
seq $(wc -l file1 | cut -d' ' -f1) | paste - file1 >file2
```

Or even a plain shell script:

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    let count++
    printf '%d\t%s\n' $count "$line"
done <file1 >file2
```

But `less` is the wrong tool. :)

Comment: So, the problem is related to the command I have chosen. WHy is that?

Comment: @mayailias Not sure what kind of answer you expect to this.  The UNIX philosophy is to use programs that do one thing well.  `less` is good at browsing files interactively, not at processing them.  There are people around who are inclined to write long rants about all that.  I'm not one them, sorry. :)

Comment: @Icd047 Very USEFUL especially the way you handle the leading spaces.

Comment: Note that `-n` is not a standard option to `cat`.

Comment: For `nl`, that assumes there's no line that contains a sequence of 1 to 3 `\:` (use `-d $'\n'` (assuming a ksh93-compatible shell) to avoid that special processing).

Comment: Note that `sed 's/\n/\t/'` is not standard. Use `sed $'s/\\n/\t/'` (assuming a ksh93-compatible shell) or `sed "$(printf 's/\\n/\t/')"`.

Comment: Note that `let` is not standard shell syntax. POSIXly, you can use `count=$((count + 1))`

Comment: `grep -n .` would remove the empty lines or the lines that don't contain any valid character. `grep -n '^'` to retain them

Comment: `wc -l file1 | cut -d' ' -f1` won't work with all `wc` implementations as some include leading spaces in the output `wc -l < file1` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

At first guess (you'll have to dig its source code for confirmation) `less` is a user interface tool: it changes the terminal behaviour. You can see `less` like a lightweight shell (it has internal commands such as `/` for searching). What you see may not be redirected. Literally: it has *no* [standard] output.

The proper tool for the job you require is `nl`, like [jimmij](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217036/redirect-output-of-less-utility-to-a-file#comment368527_217036) suggested.

Comment: This is interesting. Could you provide me with more detailed information

Comment: Sure. What more do you want to know exactly?

Comment: I just wanted to know if this  feature used by       less has some good advantages over speed  as example or other things. @jimmij  said that " if it is not terminal, then all "operations" in the buffer are thrown away." So I am a little bit curious about the reason behind this.

Comment: Speed? Well, it is a *user-interaction* tool so I fail to guess what kind of speed-related operation you'd have in mind. As for the "terminal operation" `less` discards the standard output, i.e. anything that does not directly go to the terminal so if you try to pipe or redirect its output to anything, you'll get nothing. By design, `less` is not the right tool to process text stream, which `awk`, `sed`, `grep` and many more were made for. The reason is, well, because it is a  *user-interaction* tool: it does display text on a terminal, just that and does it well.

Comment: I'll add that you won't find [m]any things such as «*Swiss Army Knives*» in UNIX because the commonly known prerogatives are: «*do [just]* one *thing but do it* well». If you need a knife, you'll find robust, reliable, sharp blades, one for copper, one for porcelain, one for flesh, one for steel, one for carton, one for granite, one for kevlar, one for glass, aso. You won't find a blade that cuts through anything with the same characteristics. The strength of the tools come from how they can be combined. In that regard, `less`is an *end* tool for displaying results on a *terminal*, period.